# Error when setting Foreign Key in SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, ddl

I've looked this up and I see that I'm doing it right but when I go to execute it, I get this error:

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "HOSPITALCODE": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE "Hospital" (
HospitalCode number,
HospitalName varchar(75),
HospitalStreet varchar(100),
HospitalCity varchar(75),
HospitalState varchar(12),
HospitalZip number,
HospitalPhone varchar(15),
CONSTRAINT HospitalCode_pk
PRIMARY KEY(HospitalCode));

CREATE TABLE "Doctor" (
DoctorID number,
DoctorFirstName varchar(75),
DoctorLastName varchar(75),
DoctorOfficeNumber number,
DoctorPhone varchar(10),
CONSTRAINT DoctorID_pk
PRIMARY KEY(DoctorID),
CONSTRAINT HospitalCode_fk
FOREIGN KEY (HospitalCode)
REFERENCES "Hospital" (HospitalCode));
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should avoid using quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble in the long run then they are worth it

Comment: Okay.  Thank you.  I changed them

Answer (score 3):

You are creating the foreign key `HospitalCode_fk` in the table `doctor` without creating the column `HospitalCode` in this table:

```
CREATE TABLE "Doctor" (
 DoctorID number,
 DoctorFirstName varchar(75),
 DoctorLastName varchar(75),
 DoctorOfficeNumber number,
 DoctorPhone varchar(10),
 HospitalCode number, /* added */
 CONSTRAINT DoctorID_pk
 PRIMARY KEY(DoctorID),
 CONSTRAINT HospitalCode_fk
 FOREIGN KEY (HospitalCode)
 REFERENCES "Hospital" (HospitalCode)
);
```

Comment: Okay.  So I made the change but I got this error:

    SQL Error: ORA-02264: name already used by an existing constraint
    02264. 00000 -  "name already used by an existing constraint"
    *Cause:    The specified constraint name has to be unique.
    *Action:   Specify a unique constraint name for the constraint.

Comment: This means that you have another constraint in your DB with the same name ( HospitalCode_fk); try changing the name of the constraint